# Form HTML with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-tag-manager

Im trying to add a simple form in a custom html tag manager.

```
 <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwZezgQCL5oLqGTfY5_eQxzWCFCy6alsgk6HOJLP0UcanoK6Gsp/exec" method="GET" class="ch-form myForm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="ch-form-row">
        <label for="input_ico">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" name="newletter_name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="ch-form-row">
        <label for="input_ico">Sexo:</label>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
    </div>
    <div class="ch-form-actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

But I can't publish it, because this error:

Invalid Template    modal   Invalid HTML, CSS, or JavaScript found in template.

Any idea why? HTML Form is not suportted by GTM?

Comment: Is this the full document? If you don't have it, then try adding a call to <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
novalidate="novalidate" ---> not supported
placeholder ----> not supported
```

Just remove this.